# Zurb Joyride not following defined order

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-joyride

Please review my [Sample Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jlnewnam/ALt2E/embedded/result/)...

When it initiates, it starts with the First Stop, and moves onto the Second and Third Stops. When it's ready to move onto the Fourth Stop, it skips and immediately jumps to a modal.

Everything is setup the way the [documentation](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/joyride.html) states.

This is the script to call the function...

```
  $(window).load(function() {
    $('#joyRideTipContent').joyride({
      autoStart : true,
      postStepCallback : function (index, tip) {
      if (index == 2) {
        $(this).joyride('set_li', false, 1);
      }
    },
    modal:true,
    expose: true
    });
  });
```

I'm completely lost as to why an item is completely skipped over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code works as expected if you remove the `postStepCallback` function:

```
postStepCallback : function (index, tip) {
      if (index == 2) {
        $(this).joyride('set_li', false, 1);
      }
    }
```

if you don't need it, don't use it.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/jeWTv/

Comment: You nailed it Irvin. I wish they would include things like that in their docs. I'm still new to JS and didn't realize I wouldn't need it. Thanks! Keep on coding!

Comment: @webfrogs glad to help you! Keep on coding :-)